# remove the add new page with no plugins

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i want to remove users the ability to add new pages in wordpress. but sill can edit them.

im using Members plugin but for them its all or nothing. i can hide all of the Pages (including the edit and reading capabilities). i have tried a few more big plugins how do the same.
so i want to write my on code.

i have found some help but for only part of the problem

for example this code remove only the sidemen but dont remove the add new button in the wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page page
or in the upper menu

```
function disable_new_pages() {
    // Hide sidebar link
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=page'][10]);

    // Hide link on listing page
    if (isset($_GET['post_type']) && $_GET['post_type'] == 'page') {
        echo '<style type="text/css">
        #favorite-actions, .add-new-h2, .tablenav { display:none; }
        </style>';
     }
    }
    add_action('admin_menu', 'disable_new_pages');
```

how can i remove this completely

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, I found a solution that help me. And I redirect unwanted users from the page. Simpler than anything (in my opinion)

```
   function my_restrict_access() {
        global $pagenow;

        if( current_user_can('client') && $pagenow == 'post-new.php' && ! current_user_can( 'publish_posts' ) )
              wp_redirect( admin_url() .'/edit.php?post_type=page' );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_restrict_access', 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do that, but lets do it in the easiest/best one :

go to **wp-includes/post.php** and search for `'capability_type' => 'page',`

and add

```
   'capabilities' => array(
        'create_posts' => false,
    ),
```

It will look like this:

```
'capability_type'       => 'page',
            'capabilities' => array(
                'create_posts' => false,
            ),
            'map_meta_cap' => true,
            'menu_position' => 20,
```

`'map_meta_cap' => true,` //  With this set to true, users will still be able to edit & delete posts

Comment: I'm going to close it according to the וuser role. Isn't this way going to be problematic that way?

Comment: @Kujtim Neziraj Don't edit the core, never !

Answer (score 0):

```
function hide_add_new_page_button(){
    echo ('<style>a[href~="post-new.php?post_type=page"], .page-title-action { display: none !important; }</style>');
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_add_new_page_button');
```